# Why does ckeditor_config make it impossible to update Composer packages?

Tags: composer

I've got a Drupal 9.4 site that I've upgraded my database stack (XAMPP dev stack) to the latest version that is using php 8.1, but now have package incompatibilities showing up when I try to run "composer udpdate". Even trying to update with all dependencies fails.
My site runs fine, however I can no longer update anything in composer without fixing whatever dependency issues there are. This is what it tells me are the problems:

```
Problem 1
- zendframework/zend-feed[dev-master, dev-develop, 2.11.0, ..., 2.13.x-dev] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laminas/laminas-feed[2.12.0, ..., 2.12.x-dev] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
- symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v1.1.0, ..., 1.1.x-dev] require php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
- symfony-cmf/routing[1.4.0-RC1, ..., 1.4.x-dev] require php ^5.3.9|^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
- symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v1.2.0, ..., v1.3.0] require php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laminas/laminas-feed[2.13.0, ..., 2.14.x-dev] require php ^7.3 || ~8.0.0 -> your php version (8.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
- drupal/core[8.9.11, ..., 8.9.x-dev] require php ^7.0.8 -> your php version (8.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
- drupal/ckeditor_config[3.0.0-beta1, ..., 3.x-dev] require drupal/ckeditor ^8.5 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.5.0-alpha1, ..., 8.9.x-dev].
- drupal/core[8.5.0-alpha1, ..., 8.7.7] require symfony-cmf/routing ^1.4 -> satisfiable by symfony-cmf/routing[1.4.0-RC1, ..., 1.4.x-dev].
- drupal/core[8.7.8, ..., 8.9.10] require symfony/psr-http-message-bridge ^1.1.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v1.1.2, 1.1.x-dev, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
- drupal/core[8.8.0-alpha1, ..., 8.8.x-dev] require zendframework/zend-feed ^2.12 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-feed[2.12.0, ..., 2.19.x-dev], zendframework/zend-feed[2.12.0, 2.12.x-dev, 2.13.x-dev].
- Root composer.json requires drupal/ckeditor_config ^3.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/ckeditor_config[3.0.0-beta1, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.x-dev].
```

My composer.json file looks like this:

```
    {
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "web/modules/custom/*"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.7",
        "drupal/acl": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.1",
        "drupal/ckeditor_config": "^3.0",
        "drupal/config_inspector": "^1.3",
        "drupal/console": "^1.9",
        "drupal/content_access": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/content_browser": "^1.0",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.4",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9.4",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.4",
        "drupal/csp": "^1.15",
        "drupal/d8w3css": "^2.0",
        "drupal/devel": "^5.0.0-beta1",
        "drupal/devel_entity_updates": "^4.0",
        "drupal/domain": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/domain_group": "^2.0",
        "drupal/domain_site_settings": "^1.3",
        "drupal/dropzonejs": "^2.4",
        "drupal/dynamic_entity_reference": "^1.12",
        "drupal/editor_advanced_link": "^1.8",
        "drupal/entity_browser": "^2.5",
        "drupal/entity_embed": "^1.1",
        "drupal/fancy_file_delete": "^2.0",
        "drupal/file_delete": "^1.0",
        "drupal/filefield_paths": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/formblock": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/gdoc_field": "^1.1",
        "drupal/group": "^1.5",
        "drupal/groupmedia": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/ief_table_view_mode": "^2.2",
        "drupal/inline_entity_form": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/item_bucket": "*",
        "drupal/jsonapi_extras": "^3.19",
        "drupal/jsonapi_include": "^1.4",
        "drupal/libraries": "^3.0@beta",
        "drupal/media_bulk_upload": "^3.0",
        "drupal/media_directories": "^2.0",
        "drupal/media_entity_instagram": "^3.0",
        "drupal/multiple_fields_remove_button": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.8",
        "drupal/pdf": "^1.1",
        "drupal/profile": "^1.2",
        "drupal/rabbit_hole": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/responsive_menus": "^1.x-dev",
        "drupal/restui": "^1.20",
        "drupal/rules": "^3.0@alpha",
        "drupal/showcase_lite": "^1.3",
        "drupal/taxonomy_manager": "^2.0",
        "drupal/textarea_widget_for_text": "^1.2",
        "drupal/video_embed_spotify": "^1.5",
        "drupal/weight": "^3.3",
        "drush/drush": "^11",
        "kint-php/kint": "^4.2"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "drupal/console-extend-plugin": true,
            "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library"
            ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
                "homepage",
                "support"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried individually updating each listed dependency, (ie composer update zendframework/zend-feed -W), etc, and they seem to run, but no updates are found and nothing is changing. How can I correct these dependency issues?

Comment: Please tell us the command you typed which resulted in the `Problem 1` output above. Much of the output is `drupal/core[8.9.11, ..., 8.9.x-dev] require php ^7.0.8 -> your php version (8.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.`, which is obvious.

Comment: This is the result of running "$ composer update",  with or without the -W (--with-all-dependencies) flag. Clearly it doesn't like the newer php, but I thought Drupal 9 is compatible with PHP 8+ so its surprising there is an issue or not an update to make everything compatible with Drupal 9, compatible with php8.

Comment: How did this site get into this situation? The `composer.json` you pasted above is not a valid JSON file so I can't test. Drupal 9 is fully compatible with PHP 8 but that doesn't mean the specific set of dependencies in that file and in the lockfile are compatible with PHP 8.

Comment: it's valid, the question formatting code/paragraph cut off the last "}". I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem package is `drupal/ckeditor_config`. This is a packaging bug that is being discussed in these issues:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_config/issues/3309026
- https://www.drupal.org/project/project_composer/issues/3309665

Comment: Yes, this is correct. It has affected many downstream modules that depend on this.

Comment: Yeah, the "drupal/ckeditor_config": "^3.0" was the issue, thanks so much!